# How can I force request session timeout for a specific capybara test or request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara, capybara-webkit

This is the contents of my `session_store.rb` file:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_myapp_session', expire_after: (Rails.env.production? ? 2.hours : 3.minute)
```

I would like to run a test when a request is submitted against a timed-out session from an anonymous (not logged-in) user:

```
scenario 'Submit form when session has timed out' do
  # Not logged in user
  visit my_form_path

  # set session timeout to 1 second or force cookie session timeout
  ????

  click_button('Submit')

  # Verify expectations
  ...
end
```

I'm using rails 4.2, capybara 2.12, and capybara-webkit 1.12, rspec 3.3. I'm also using devise 4.2, but my scenario if for an anonymous user.

When I run my app on development, I can wait till session times out and I see the app is working as expected, but I want to have this tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is currently not possible to force a cookie session timeout with capybara-webkit.

https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/978